# Bukkit EventHandler ignores if statement

Tags: java, arraylist, bukkit

When I run this code on my bukkit server version 1.8.4 it ignores the if statement always. But I get no Error.
Do you have any idea?

I will explain how my plugin works.
1. I create an ArrayList with the name Logger. In this ArrayList I will save Players
2. the public void `PlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){}` is a Event that is triggered when a player is joined.
3. The Event is triggered and I define a Player p. I get this Player from the Event.
4. I ask: if Logger contains my Player p is false then add me to the Logger ArrayList. After that print the Logger list in the chat.

Now when I join the first time on a server I were added to the Logger list and the plugin sends me the list. Now I am only in the list. But when I join again then the If-statement runs again and I get added to the Loggerlist again and can see that I am two time in the list. But I don't know why because the if statement should now be false and not be executed.

```
ArrayList<Player> Logger = new ArrayList<Player>();

//Player On Join
@EventHandler
public void PlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    if(!Logger.contains(p)){
        Logger.add(p);
        p.sendMessage("list: " + Logger);
    }else {
        p.sendMessage("You are already in the List!");
    }
}
```

Comment: try debugging it. see if p is what you think it is, and verify it next to the contents of the arrayList. In your player method, did you override the equals and hashCode methods?

Comment: thx for your tipps but I already debug it and I don´t override any method.

Comment: Then  that's your problem. You must override the equals and hashcode methods and implement them correctly. Now it's using a referential comparison, and since they don't share the same reference, the contains method returns false.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my Problem!

```
ArrayList<String> Logger = new ArrayList<String>();
//Player On Join
@EventHandler
public void PlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
Player p = e.getPlayer();
if(!Logger.contains(p.getName())){
    Logger.add(p.getName());
    p.sendMessage("list: " + Logger);
}else {
    p.sendMessage("You are already in the List!");
}
}
```

Comment: This works because a Player object stores it's coordinates, inventory, etc., not just the name, so `notch` at `-3, 52, 67` is not the same player as `notch` at `0, 128, 0`.